# android.os.ServiceSpecificException: GPIO2_IO02 is already in use (code 16)

Tags: gpio, android-things

I am working on android things(Pico i.MX7D I/O).I got **android.os.ServiceSpecificException: GPIO2_IO02 is already in use (code 16)** exception,What it means by this? Please help me.

My sample program is cloned from
 https://github.com/androidthings/sample-button.

Comment: Based on the post you've made, I would recommend spending some time reading documentation in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) so that you have the best chance at getting your question answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means another app is running in the background and is currently accessing this pin. This may happen if one app is not fully stopped before a new one is opened.

You can see all your installed apps by running: `adb shell pm list packages -3`

You can force stop a program by running `adb shell am force-stop <package name>`

Uninstalling or force stopping the rogue app should allow you to properly get control of it.

Edit: As a comment pointed out, I did not include the command to do uninstalling. `adb uninstall <package-name>`

Comment: The only thing left is to find out which app is using the pin :)

Comment: You could probably uninstall most of your third-party apps.

Comment: @Diljith use this script to uninstall all AndroidThings app at once: https://gist.github.com/blundell/7c0c3bb17898b28fe8122b0dc230af50