# UART Cannot Open or Already in use

Tags: raspberry-pi, uart, android-things

I'm trying to Close and Open UART in every activity sometimes while I'm trying to open the UART it show's Exception: UART cant open com.google.android.things.pio.PioException: android.os.ServiceSpecificException: UART0 is already in use (code 16)

Comment: This seems to be similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48437428/android-os-servicespecificexception-gpio2-io02-is-already-in-use-code-16

Comment: What methods are you overwriting to open and close in? because your new activity can be created before the previous is destroyed

Comment: I'm closing the port before starting the intent.even i added some timer between closing the port and calling the intent