# Why is GPIO still in use after closing it?

Tags: android, iot, android-things

I have an issue with GPIO after the closing of it. The first step I closed the GPIO by calling of the method close() and after that, I tried to open it again, but PeripheralManager throws exception android.os.ServiceSpecificException: BCM17 is already in use (code 16). Why does there happen?

Snippet of the code for example:

```java
Gpio gpio = PeripheralManager.getInstance().openGpio("BCM17");
.
.
// do some interactions with opened GPIO
.
.
gpio.close();

Gpio gpio1 = PeripheralManager.getInstance().openGpio("BCM17"); //throws exception android.os.ServiceSpecificException: BCM17 is already in use (code 16)
```

Comment: It's hard to help you without the source code.

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenko I've added code snippet

Comment: @Eugene It means it still working here is a link it maybe helpfull [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48437428/android-os-servicespecificexception-gpio2-io02-is-already-in-use-code-16] Could you try reset your rasperry after giving this error and try again to see ıt gives the same error to check is there any app to use these port

Comment: Why do you need to close and reopen gpio? Why not use once opened gpio an close it only in `onDestroy()`?

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenko My main idea is about changing device configuration on the fly. I thought that the method `Gpio#close()` releases GPIO port and there is possible to use it in the scope of the same application without device/app reloading. Cause it isn't clear description of the method `close()` that says "This must be called in order for the GPIO pin to be released and be available to other users.", what does it mean "available to other users", is it available to other application or available to use in scope of run application?

Comment: @Nazim on the raspberry other applications weren't installed.

Comment: @Eugene You can reconfigure pin without `close()` call.

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenko thank you, you are right and gave me an idea, it's a problem in architecture of the application, I will change it and get that I need

Comment: @Eugene You're welcome! Good luck!